# Can I obtain the `maxlength` of a field in a Mongoose Schema?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Lets say I have a Mongoose Schema like this:

```
import { Schema, Document, model } from 'mongoose';
let MySchema = new Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength: [200, 'Must be {MAXLENGTH} characers or less.']
    }   
}, { collection: 'mystuff' });


const MyModel = model('MyStuff', MySchema);

export { MyModel };
```

Is there a way I can check what the `maxlength` is on the `name` attribute from `MyModel`?